# CVS check out i get four options. What do they mean?

Tags: branch, cvs, head

When I am checking out an application i get four options HEAD, Branches, Versions and Dates what do they mean? What is the difference between each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A code repository is a tree of versions, each of which represents the state of the code at some particular point. It's possible to create a new branch of the tree from any point. Thus…

- **HEAD** is the tip of the main trunk of the tree.
- A **branch** is some other route through the tree of versions (e.g., to support a particular set of releases or develop a feature). If you ask to check out a branch, you typically get the tip of that branch.
- A **version** represents an exact state of the code. In CVS, versions are per-file. (Other source control systems have global versioning.)
- A **date**-based checkout represents getting the state of the code at a particular moment. This can be very useful for tracking down bugs.

The other thing that you'll see is a tagged version. That's where a name is given to a particular state of the tree (e.g., to represent an exact release).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Open Source Development with CVS](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html), especially the [Branches](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#Branches) chapter. That explains how CVS works and what the head revision is and what branches are.